# ¿Cómo cambiar las vistas de SwiftUI de una manera que no acumule retraso con el tiempo?

Tags: swift, rendimiento

Hice [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292634/how-do-i-go-to-another-view-in-swiftui-programmatically-using-button-action) pregunta y acepté una respuesta e intenté usar ese código. **Mi problema con la nueva respuesta aceptada es que cuando tengo muchas vistas, se vuelve muy desordenada y no se compila.**  Parecía que funcionó. Pero poco sabía que había un problema discreto. Mi problema es que uso el código similar al que aparece en la respuesta para crear un menú principal y una página de configuración. La página de configuración tiene un botón listo que lleva de vuelta al menú principal. Ahora aquí está el problema: parece estar bien al principio, pero cada vez que cambio, de alguna manera la vista anterior no se elimina o algo que no sé. Pero lo que sí sé es que, una vez que cambio a la configuración y retrocedo suficientes veces, se vuelve lento, y cuando uso el comando superior en la terminal, está consumiendo una cantidad increíble de gpu. Aquí están los códigos de referencia, aunque todavía no estoy agregando botones de configuración de botones que no sean atrás:

Home.swift

```
import SwiftUI
struct Home: View {
        @State var ToOptions: Bool = false
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                if (ToOptions) {
                    Options();
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.ToOptions.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Settings")
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Settings.swift

```
import SwiftUI
struct Settings: View {
        @State var ToHome: Bool = false
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                if (ToHome) {
                    Home()
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.ToHome.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Back")
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

¿Por qué es tan lento y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

La razón por la que sospecho (pero no estoy seguro de que esto sea cierto) es que de alguna manera no puede eliminar la vista anterior al cambiar a la nueva, por lo que genera vistas abandonadas que con el tiempo causan retraso. Y si mi hipótesis es correcta, dígame cómo "eliminar" las vistas antiguas al ingresar una nueva. Por favor ayuda, ojalá tuviera suficiente representante para ofrecer una recompensa. Bueno, estoy codificando para macOS, pero por la naturaleza del problema, no veo cómo la plataforma que uso marcaría la diferencia. Encontré algo, como se especifica la respuesta aceptada en la pregunta vinculada, sin embargo, eso solo funciona si tengo algunas vistas. En este caso, Xcode no puede compilar con 3, y mi aplicación terminada tendrá, hmmm. déjame hacer los cálculos. 20. Por lo menos. Entonces necesito una solución alternativa. Mi problema con la respuesta en la pregunta vinculada es que no permite la programación de varios archivos.

```
import SwiftUI
struct MainMenu: View {
    @State var ToMainMenu:Bool = false
    @State var ToSingleplayer:Bool = false
    @State var ToNewWorld:Bool = false
    @State var ToMultiplayer:Bool = false
    @State var ToOptions:Bool = false
    @State var ToGraphics:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if (self.ToSingleplayer) {

            } else if (self.ToMultiplayer) {

            } else if (self.ToOptions) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(String(cString: OptionsString()))
                            .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                        HStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                            VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: GraphicsString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: LanguageString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: ControlsString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: HelpString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                            VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: AudioString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: UserInterfaceString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: CompatibilityString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: AboutString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                        }
                        Button (action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.ToOptions.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(String(cString: DoneString()))
                                .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)*3, maxWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)*3)
                                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                } // Options
            } else if (self.ToGraphics) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(String(cString: GraphicsString()))
                            .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                        HStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                            VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: SkyRenderingModeString()))
                                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                        .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                        .lineLimit(2)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                            VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                                Button (action: {

                                }) {
                                    Text(String(cString: ReducedParticlesString()))
                                    .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                    .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/8)*3)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                    .lineLimit(2)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                }
                                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            }
                        }
                        Button (action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.ToGraphics.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(String(cString: DoneString()))
                                .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                .frame(minWidth: ((geometry.size.width/4)*3), maxWidth: ((geometry.size.width/4)*3))
                                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                } //Graphics
            } else if (self.ToMainMenu) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    VStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("JTCraft")
                            .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/8))
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            self.ToSingleplayer.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text(String(cString: SingleplayerString()))
                                .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2, maxWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
                                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.ToMultiplayer.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text(String(cString: MultiplayerString()))
                                .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                .frame(minWidth: geometry.size.width/2, maxWidth: geometry.size.width/2)
                                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        HStack (spacing: geometry.size.width/48) {
                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation {
                                    self.ToOptions.toggle()
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text(String(cString: OptionsString()))
                                    .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                    .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                            }
                                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            Button(action: {
                                HandleApplicationClose()
                            }) {
                                Text(String(cString: QuitGameString()))
                                    .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/24))
                                    .frame(minWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-geometry.size.width/96, maxWidth: (geometry.size.width/4)-geometry.size.width/96)
                                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.init(white: 0.4)))
                                    .lineLimit(1)
                            }
                                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                } //Main Menu
            } else {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("Julian's Ripoffs of Minecraft®")
                        .font(.system(size: geometry.size.width/8))
                        .onAppear() {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.5) {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.ToMainMenu.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Aquí está mi código actual que es imposible de compilar, pero no acumula retraso al cambiar de vista.

­